# Intellij Connect to Docker MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, docker, intellij-idea

I have a problem connecting to a docker mysql DB through the Intellij UI.

I am able to connect using the following command through the terminal:

`mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -p db_name --password=password`

Note the user of the `--protocol` flag, without this I could not connect. In addition, I assume that since I can connect through the terminal to the docker DB then setup is correct, i.e. the port is exposed and I am able to connect.

In Intellij I use the following connection settings - I am not sure where you specify the protocol of the connection, in case this resolved the issue. I've also tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost which as I read will use the tcp protocol. But no luck.

I've tried the latest MYSQL Driver (8) for the connection as well as the MySQL for 5.1 version.

The error I get is the following(though the password and username are triple checked, and I am able to connect through the terminal):

> The specified database user/password combination is rejected:
> [28000][1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
> password: YES)

[image: Intellij Screenshot]

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which error do you get? Please try this - open up data source properties, switch to Advanced tab and paste this into VM options field:  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  . then try to connect.

Comment: @YuriWin thanks for your help but unfortunately still no luck. Do you know maybe how can I explicitly specify the connection protocol to tcp? or any other ideas?